# How to access a variable within a function

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

How do I access a variable that is defined within a function like this:

```
var functionVar = function(){
  this.var = 1;
}

console.log(functionVar().var); //MH - obviously this doesn't work, but I'm looking for the command that will log that variable
```

Comment: "functionVar.var" doesn't work ? Why adding parenthesis to a variable ?

Comment: That's not a "variable" - it's an object property.

Comment: Ah true, it's not a instance.

Comment: That's a wrong example, but if you are looking for a way to access variables defined in a function (local variables) then the answer is "you can't".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access like this,

```
var functionVar = function(){
  this.var = 1;
}

 var o = new functionVar();
 alert(o.var)​
```

Comment: That's a property on the constructed object. Not a variable. Are we certain this function was meant to be used as a constructor?

Comment: Yes, it's not a variable. My bad english.

Answer (score 0):

a **new** will do the trick.

```
var functionVar = function(){
  this.var = 1;
}

console.log(new functionVar().var);
```

Though not sure what you are trying to achieve by using this code.